# Use C# to write array elements from jsonstring to csv or xlsx

Tags: c#, excel

I tried to write array of string from JsonString into the 1st column of excel file(either csv or xslx). and the code is creating a csv file as in screen2. How can I get the excel sheet to look like screen1 ?

```
input JsonResponse =

{"wordAlterations":[{"alterations":["hm","history matching","HM","History Matching"]},{"alterations":["risk taking","Risk Taking","RISK TAKING","risk-taking","Risk-Taking","RISK-TAKING"]}]}
```

Here is my sample code

```
 string line = string.Empty;

 List<string> newLines = new List<string>();

 Rooter myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rooter>(jsonResponse);

 foreach(var alter in myDeserializedClass.wordAlterations)
 {
     line = string.Join(",", alter.alterations.Select(item =>"'"+ item+"'"));                         

     newLines.Add(line);
 }

 File.AppendAllLines("sample.csv", newLines);
```

Expected `.csv` file - note the array is written into column A, line1 and line2 with each item in double quotes.

[image]

Actual CSV I get:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to include the double quote but you don't know how to escape it? How about this:

```
line = string.Join(",", alter.alterations.Select(item =>"\"" + item + "\""));
```

UPDATE: Changed implementation on some parts of your code:

```
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        List<string> newLines = new List<string>();

        Rooter myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rooter>(jsonResponse);

        foreach (var alter in myDeserializedClass.wordAlterations)
        {
            sb.Append(string.Join(",", alter.alterations.Select(item => "'" + item + "'")));
            sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
        }

        File.AppendAllText("sample.csv", sb.ToString());
```

Changes:

1. Used StringBuilder to form the string and appended a new line every loop
2. Instead of AppendAllLines, I used AppendAllText

The reason why I used StringBuilder is so that the loop will form it as one string when the ToString method is called.

[image]

Comment: @ we want  the text to remain in the first column only and do not want the each array item go into separate columns.

Comment: @roney updated with some implementation changes. check it out..